# Getting Style Name of a specific view - Android

Tags: android, styles

I have an EditText and a custom Style, and I would like to know how I can programmatically, get the "name" of this style, like below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/idValue"
    style="@style/integerNumber"
    ... />
```

In the code,

```
EditText edValue = findViewById (R.id.idValue);
```

In this case, I need to receive "integerNumber". Is there a specific method to get this information? (such as edValue.getResources().getStyle()) ... I could not find at all.

Comment: sorry i missunderstanding question, now i think its not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't. Looking at the [view constructor](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/21e6e2de1f0062f949fcc52d0b4559dfa3246e0e/core/java/android/view/View.java#L1902) (in particular ), the style is used just to define view's properties but it's thrown away afterwards. It is not stored anywhere, so I guess you can't retrieve it from the view object.

If you need to get the style you can still (conventionally) [add a tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atag) to the views and behave according to that.

Comment: :(
Thank you anyway ... it is not a good answer for me, I am going to see what I have to do now

Comment: Adding a tag with the name of the style and getting it from code is pretty straightforward and is the way I'd go for...